# How to get value of child element of Object collection using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have HTMLTable with some rows and columns. I'm binding a function to the cell of this table on click. Inside this function I need to get value of first cell in this selected row.
I have the following:

[image]

```
$(this).parent().children() 
gives me object with 4 HTMLTableCellElement like on the picture
```

I need to get text that contains innerHTML of [0] element:

[image]

How to get this text?

```
If I use $(this).parent().children('0').innerHTML it gives me "undefined"
```

Comment: `this.parentNode.cells[0].innerHTML`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.children()` returns an array of DOM elements. You can simply grab the first element in the array:

```
$(this).parent().children()[0].innerHTML
```

Answer (score 3):

Pretty close, try:

```
$(this).parent("tr").find("td:first").text();
```